# Equation of hyperplane in Matlab

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, matlab, computational-geometry

Given $n$ points in $n$-dimensions, using MatLab, how should we find the equation of the $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplane passing through these $n$ points.

Comment: I think you mean $(n-1)$-dimensional plane.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the given points be
$$
p_1 = \left[\begin{matrix} p_{11} \\ p_{12} \\ \vdots \\ p_{1n} \end{matrix}\right]
\quad\text{,}\quad
p_2 = \left[\begin{matrix} p_{21} \\ p_{22} \\ \vdots \\ p_{2n} \end{matrix}\right]
\quad\text{,}\quad
\dots
\quad\text{,}\quad
p_n = \left[\begin{matrix} p_{n1} \\ p_{n2} \\ \vdots \\ p_{nn} \end{matrix}\right]
$$
You want to find $a_1,\dotsc,a_n,c$ such that the equation
$$ a_1 x_1 + \dotsc + a_n x_n = c $$
is satisfied by all the $p_i$.  In other words, you want the $a_i$ and $c$ to be a solution of
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} & \dots & p_{1n} & -1 \\
p_{21} & p_{22} & \dots & p_{2n} & -1 \\
& \vdots \\
p_{n1} & p_{n2} & \dots & p_{nn} & -1 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \\ c
\end{matrix}\right]
=
\left[\begin{matrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
So, tell Matlab to solve that system... however you tell Matlab to do such things.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This system of homogeneous linear equations `Ax = 0` can be solved in MatLab by using the command `null(A)`